# count cell with color

Tags: excel, colors, count, cell

I want to count number of cell filled with specific color.

For ex. Few cell are red, few are green few are yellow.

Now I want to count total red/green/yellow.

Is there any idea how could I apply it over merged cell also.

A prompt response will be appreciated.

Regards.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? If the color is controlled by conditional formatting, directly count the cells which satisfy the conditions. If the color is directly chosen by the user, a VBA solution is required. In this case, the architecture of the spreadsheet is somewhat suspect -- using color to convey and not just highlight information is error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the instructions on the link below with the mentioned change below the link.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2815384

**Change:** Change the script given in the link to the following, as the script from microsoft uses color index which may count other shades of a color.

```
Function CountColor(range_data As range, criteria As range) As Long
    Dim datax As range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    xcolor = criteria.Interior.color
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.color = xcolor Then
           CountColor = CountColor + 1
        End If
    Next datax
End Function
```